# PostgreSQL bucardo schema replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, bucardo

I want to replicate all tables from specific `PostgreSQL` **schemas**. So new tables from these schemas to be added automatically in synchronization.

Is it possible to do with `Bucardo`? If not, what tool would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any "well known" tool that makes logical replication of DDL statements.

From https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31276/15606

> PostgreSQL native streaming replication reads changes at the block
> level from the write-ahead logs, so the databases are kept physically
> the same. Since DDL is, just like DML, recorded in the WAL, DDL and
> DML are both transparently replicated.

But as you want to select some specific schemas logical replication is needed. Neither native [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/logical-replication.html) or common tools like Bucardo, [Slony](https://slony.info/) allow to replicate DDL.

For simple cases you should apply the database migrations with your tool of choice, for example [sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) to all databases.

For more complex cases you can try the extension [pgl_ddl_deploy](https://github.com/enova/pgl_ddl_deploy). AFAIK this extension is not well know and didn't try it myself.